# Point to directory in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a bunch of files in the `source/_static/text/` folder in Sphinx and I would like to have a link point to these files, so the readers of the documentation can go through the list of files and pick what's appropriate.

I've tried the `:download:` and `:include:` directives but neither comes close. Is there a way to do this in Sphinx?

Comment: How did you specify the path to the files? For `:include:` it must be relative to the current document. For `:download:` it is either relative to the current document or to the root (if the path starts with a slash). Do you want the files to be available for download or included verbatim?

Comment: I tried using `link <../_static/text/>` but that's relative and `_static` is only in `source` not `build`. It would be nice if a user could first browse the files before clicking on one for downloading. I don't want them included verbatim.

Comment: You must include one `:download:` directive per file. For instance `:download:/_static/text/file1.txt`. Those files will be copied this way. A simple link does not flag the files for copying in the build.

Comment: There is no way to point to a directory?

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe there is an extension that does it. It would not be overly complex to code. Or you can script the generation of an ad-hoc rst file.

Comment: Doesn't `\`Link <_static/text>\`_` work? It does for me.

Comment: When all else fails, post-process the HTML.